# ansible: multiple var files for roles?

Tags: ansible

In all ansible docs I have found, the `[role]/vars/main.yml` file is referenced as the place for role variables.

There is some customization possible by using `[role]/defaults/main.yml` which then can be overwritten by `[role]/vars/main.yml`.

What if I'd want to address a multitude of scenarios, and say load a group of vars based on a main variable, and then place the grouped vars in each file like

```
[role]/vars/main.yml
[role]/vars/scenario1.yml
[role]/vars/scenario2.yml
[role]/vars/scenario3.yml
[role]/vars/scenario4.yml
```

In other words, is there any use for the `[role]/vars` directory to contain more than just the `main.yml` file?

The concrete challenge is, define sets of users with their public keys, so depending on which machine I am, create the appropriate user accounts

Comment: I think you need to use `include_vars` to include the file of choice based on a conditional statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The role of `vars/main.yml` is not really to overwrite variables defined in `defaults/main.yml`. In fact that would actually be counter-productive as variables defined in `vars/main.yml` have a quite high [precedence level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and are harder to override while you usually want vars in `defaults/main.yml` to be easilly modified by a user.

Regarding the `vars` folder, it contains by convention files defining variables that are specific to your role. But only `vars/main.yml` will be loaded by default.

Meanwhile that folder (like the `vars` folder adjacent to your playbook if you have one) is on the search path when you `include_vars` from your role. So if I take your example, you can easilly `include_vars: scenario1.yml` somewhere in you role or even `include_vars: "scenario{{ scenario_number }}.yml"` if you get that dynamically.

**Disclaimer**: *I am the maintainer of the role taken as example below*

Here is a real life example taken from [ansible-thoteam/nexus-oss role](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss).

As you can see, this role has a [`vars` folder](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/tree/master/vars) with several files but no `default.yml`. So no role variables are loaded by default. Those files are loaded dynamically when needed.

There are 2 files related to different OS famillies supported by the role: [`configure-Debian.yml`](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/vars/configure-Debian.yml) and [`configure-RedHat.yml`](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/vars/configure-RedHat.yml). They are loaded as needed in [`tasks/main.yml`](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/3c9ef7800bf8aeda0802dc45318cb012e3426cd6/tasks/main.yml#L6) with the following task:

```yaml
- name: Include OS specific variables.
  include_vars: "configure-{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
```

Alternatively, you can have a look at the [`first_found` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html) which can also be used for this kind of scenario.